# Word for "something writtenly so vaguely that it's nearly meaningless" (like Weasel Words)

Tags: ambiguity

I'm looking for a word (or expression) for "something writtenly so vaguely that it's nearly meaningless." The context is a professional IT document that tries to use technical-sounding words, often inappropriately, to convey authority, where in effect the author says nothing substantial.

Example: "Product X is supported on Windows 10, however compatible [probably meant "companion"] products are not currently supported on this platform. A common compatible operating system must be used."

Wikipedia calls this "Weasel words: words and phrases aimed at creating an impression that something specific and meaningful has been said, when in fact only a vague or ambiguous claim has been communicated. A common form of weasel wording is through vague attribution, where a statement is dressed with authority, yet has no substantial basis."

Is there another, more formal term or expression?

NOTE: Yes, I'm aware of the comma splice joining the two independent clauses.

Comment: How about bafflegab? Maybe that's not a word. Vacuous?

Comment: There are plenty if you mean obscurantism (a deliberate policy / practice  of misleading by using unclear statements). From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obscurantism):
 
 
 
 
**obscurantism** 1:  opposition to the spread of knowledge :  a policy of withholding knowledge from the general public // 2a :  a style (as in literature or art) characterized by deliberate vagueness or abstruseness .... However, where the lack of clarity is not by design, 'Double Dutch' is an even more dubious term.

Comment: There are many terms.  "Meaningless drivel" is one that I often use.  "Gobbledygook" is another.  If you want something "formal" you can dip into a thesaurus and use, say, "sophistic wordsmithing".  Or simply "sophistry".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Grandiloquence** is a type of talk that is pompous and bombastic, full of pretty-sounding words and elegant turns of phrase that add up
>   to nothing. Politicians who say nothing but make it sound important
>   are masters of grandiloquence.

[[Vocabulary.com/dictionary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/grandiloquence)]

But I'd say using it virtually has to be hypocritical; I'd stick with 'weasel-words'.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of the word "verbiage." The synonyms below may be good options as well.

ver·bi·age
ˈvərbē-ij/
noun
1.
speech or writing that uses too many words or excessively technical expressions.
synonyms:   verbosity, wordiness, prolixity, long-windedness, loquacity, rigmarole, circumlocution